# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to set up project in localhost it gives me below error.

**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

[image]

I am new for rails and googled for solution. But nothing works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `payload` do not have any item with `:headers` as a key. So, `payload[:headers]` returns `nil` and calling `[]` over `nil` value raises `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. `controller` variable on line 17 could be `nil`?

Comment: Please, edit the question and insert code as a text, not as an image

Answer (score 2):

A common problem to encounter. It usually means that where ever you are trying to call `[]`, the value is empty. In your case, `payload[:headers]` is missing.

You can add a `debugger` before line 17 which stops the process. You can then inspect your `controller` if it contains the `payload[:headers]`.